# Scipy least_squares: "func() missing n required positional argument: 'n_1', 'n_2'..."

Tags: python, scipy, regression, least-squares, scipy-optimize

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import least_squares

##################################### Prepare Data #########################################

file = 'https://aegis4048.github.io/downloads/notebooks/sample_data/decline_curve.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name='sheet_1')
df = df[df['Oil Prod. (bopd)'] > 200]           # remove bad data points
t = df['Time'][1:].values[: -40]
y = df['Oil Prod. (bopd)'][1:].values[:-40]
x = np.array([i for i in range(len(t))])

############################################################################################


def hyperbolic(x, qi, b, Di):
    return qi / (1 + b * Di * x) ** (1 / b)

res_robust = least_squares(hyperbolic, x0=[max(y), 0.1, 0.1], args=(x, y))
```

I was able to fit it easily with `curve_fit` with this syntax:

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(hyperbolic, x, y, maxfev=100000, p0=[max(y), 0.1, 0.1])
```

But when I try to fit my data using `least_squares`, I'm getting this error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-5ee2dcc8876d> in <module>()
     20     return qi / (1 + b * Di * x) ** (1 / b)
     21 
---> 22 res_robust = least_squares(hyperbolic, x0=[max(y), 0.1, 0.1], args=(x, y,))

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_lsq\least_squares.py in least_squares(fun, x0, jac, bounds, method, ftol, xtol, gtol, x_scale, loss, f_scale, diff_step, tr_solver, tr_options, jac_sparsity, max_nfev, verbose, args, kwargs)
    797         x0 = make_strictly_feasible(x0, lb, ub)
    798 
--> 799     f0 = fun_wrapped(x0)
    800 
    801     if f0.ndim != 1:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_lsq\least_squares.py in fun_wrapped(x)
    792 
    793     def fun_wrapped(x):
--> 794         return np.atleast_1d(fun(x, *args, **kwargs))
    795 
    796     if method == 'trf':

TypeError: hyperbolic() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Di'
```

I don't understand the operational difference between `curve_fit` and `least_squares`. Can someone give me a working code that works with `least_squares`?

Comment: If I'm not much mistaken, it looks like you're missing an `arg` for the `hyperbolic` function. based on the docs, you can be 100% sure you're covered by passing in `kwargs({x: whatever x is, qi: whatever qi is, b: whatever b is, Di: whatever Di is})`

Answer (score 1):

According to the `least_squares` docs, your `fun` should have the signature:

```
fun(x, *args, **kwargs)
```

In other words it's trying to do:

```
hyperbolic(x0, x, y)     # 3 arguments
```

The `x` matches your `x0` initial value in shape; the `(x,y)` come from the `args` parameter.

For `curve_fit` the expectation is

```
ydata = f(xdata, *params)
```

So the call it

```
hyperbolic(x, p0[0], p0[1], p0[2])  # line up with
#hyperbolic(x, qi, b, Di)
```

Your `hyperbolic` signature matches the `curve_fit` call, but not the `least_squares` one.

Comment: Upvoted for the excellence and clarity of the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry but its still not clear to me. Can you give me a code that works for `least_squares` in my case? Something like `least_squares(hyperbolic(x, p0[0], p0[1], p0[2]))` Where do you input the y value to compare my fit? Giving me a working code would help me more

Comment: Have you worked through the examples in the `least_squares` docs, especially the last one.  Your function has to return the `residuals`, something like `hyperbolic(x, p0)-y`.